# When to start with year 0 and when with year 1 when calculating NPV?

Tags: investing, business

I am calculating NPV for one investment plan.
When should I start the calculation of NPV with year 0 and when with year 1?

I know that the year 0 is like the year when the company is just starting up so there are no revenues yet etc... In the first year they will be just doing everything so that in the next year they can start selling their products or services...

However, I have seen some examples of calculating NPV on the internet when there was just years 1,2,3,4 and not starting with year 0.... Is it a case of companies that do not need that first year for starting up but are able to sell their products or services from the first month after they started their business?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The income and recurring costs will be shown at the end of each year, however the initial cost is recorded at the time they are incurred meaning at t=0 (Jan 2014)

The first net profits/loss of 658500 is recorded at the end of Dec 2014 (t=1)

And the remaining four ones at the end of 2015 (t=2) 2016 (t=3) 2017 (t=4) 2018 (t=5)

-8000000 658500  658500 658500 658500 6658500

t=0) -8000000

t=1) 658500

t=2) 658500

t=3) 658500

t=4) 658500

t=5) 6658500

Answer (score 2):

When using Time Value of Money equations, you need to know when the flow starts. A mortgage for example, has a first payment at the end of the first time period, usually 1 month. 
For savings, one can start the account with a deposit of course, or start by saying "I will deposit $XXX at the end of each month. 
The answer really depends on the exact details of the situation. In your example, I'm inclined to suggest first flow is 1 year out.

Comment: Let's say the company starts in January 2014.

Comment: Then if you are performing simple TVM calculations, there's no Cash Flow at Year = 0. It's calculated like someone investing their money, with no deposit on Jan 1, 14, but saving to make the Jan 1 ,15 deposit.

Answer (score 0):

The preparation for starting up of the company has lasted already more than 2 years.
Let's say the company starts officially in January next year. So, in January 2014... 8 million USD is invested to purchase the equipments and the company will start selling their prdocuts right away. Imagine the company will be selling the same amount of products each year at the same price for 5 years. After 5 years it will sell the equipments for 6 million USD and cease to exist. The depreciation of  equipments is divided into those 5 years. So, each year the depreciation of equipments is 400.000 USD. In despite of this, the company will make 500.000 USD per year as a profit before tax. 
So, the equipments are bought in Januardy 2014 (first month of the existence of the company)
and sold in December 2018 (last month of the existence of the company).
This is the NPV that I calculated. Is it correct?

[image]

Answer (score -2):

isn't the answer in the question?  it says the company starts officially NEXT year, yet it is asking for the net present value...i.e what that project is worth today.  it could be that funds for that particular project may not be necessary for another year, but there may be other projects to evaluate against today.

Comment: t0 is (normally) when the capital flows into the project occur so tend to be one of, if not the only, negative cash flows. it has nothing to do with a company "officially" existing.